# How can i convert strings placed in JtextField component into an integer

Tags: java, swing

I'm new to java and I have tried a lot in converting strings placed in a `JTextField` Component into an integer type, but I couldn't. So kindly help me with this problem.

Comment: But... JTextField isn't an Integer. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Ondkloss This is one more case of a badly redacted question where the title has more information than the post. He is referring to the string in the JTextField and not the JTextField itself.

Comment: btw, next time use [Google like this](https://www.google.com.mx/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=convert+string+to+jtextfield&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=n6bOU7fQFMXB8AHLvYCwAg#channel=fs&q=convert+string+jtextfield+to+int) and that could lead you to: [Convert JTextField Input to Integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071211/convert-jtextfield-input-into-an-integer).

Comment: On Execution i'll enter an integer in the JTextField and i need to process the entered integer later in the code...

Comment: Look at both answers below, also check both links I gave (if you haven't done that), if you need better help please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: For the sake of common sense, use a `JSpinner` with `SpinnerNumberModel` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're trying to parse the String got from the user input on `JTextField` and not the `JTextField` at all, so it should be something like this.

```
JTextField myTextField = new JTextField();

String textFromTextField = myTextField.getText();

int number = Integer.parseInt(textFromTextField);

System.out.println(number);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Integer.parseInt(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) method.

```
int i;
try {
    i = Integer.parseInt(testField.getText()).intValue();
}
catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    // FIXME Handle your exception!
}
```